# Can you P/Invoke missing OpenTK methods in Mac Visual Studio / Xamarin?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.mac

The preview release of Visual studio for Mac uses  OpenTK 0,0,0,0 from Package Xamarin.Mac.framework

This is missing numerous calls I need,

- GL.BindVertexArray
- GL.DeleteVertexArray
- GL.GenVertexArrays

Is there some way to P/Invoke these and how should you do it? Or, where is there any good information on how to do it?

Can I remove the .dll from the */Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.Mac/OpenTK.dll* directory and replace it with one elsewhere that has these calls? (I can't use OpenTKv2 open source as Xamarin has Vector2 types, and others stored in another namespace that clash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I remove the .dll from the /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.Mac/OpenTK.dll directory and replace it with one elsewhere that has these calls? (I can't use OpenTKv2 open source as Xamarin has Vector2 types, and others stored in another namespace that clash)

No, not safely. Replacing random assemblies from inside Xamarin.Mac will not lead to happy results.

> Is there some way to P/Invoke these and how should you do it? Or,
>   where is there any good information on how to do it?

Yes, for C functions, like this the standard DllImport should work fine. You can find some examples [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/master/src/OpenGL/OpenTK/Graphics/OpenGL/GLCore.cs).

Comment: Please also consider filing bugs bugzilla.xamarin.com/index.cgi for missing bindings so they get fixed.

Comment: Awesome - Ill take a look later tonight. I've filed he bugs through the 'report a problem' before asking this. Does that get to bugzilla?

Comment: Chris - the link you provided seems to point to the latest open source version of xamarin.mac - am I right? I am guessing this isn't used in the preview version of Mac Visual Studio as it **does** seem to have the methods mentioned. [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/visual-studio-mac/) says it uses mono 4.6 where the latest is mono 4.8 -  I guess this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So after Chris's answer I created a class below

```
public static class PInvoke
{ 
public const string file = "/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/OpenGL";
#if __MAC__

[DllImport(file, EntryPoint = "glBindVertexArray", ExactSpelling = true)]
    internal extern static void BindVertexArray(UInt32 array);
#endif
}
```

Then from the another class used

```
PInvoke.glBindVertexArray((uint) _vertexBuffer._VAO_ID);
```

and it just works instead of

```
GL.BindVeryexArray((uint) _vertexBuffer._VAO_ID)
```